# Hibernate Upgrade : StatisticsService()

Tags: java, hibernate, upgrade

I am upgrading hibernate from 3.6 to 4.3.5.

After replacing the `.jar` files and some deprecated packages, classes & also the Basic data types I am still getting some errors with the `StatisticsService()` & in `org.hibernate.jmx` package.

The errors are following:

```
 1. error: package org.hibernate.jmx does not exist
    [javac] import org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService;
 2. error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] StatisticsService stats = new StatisticsService(); // MBean implementation
```

Is there any other method to implement this OR the package itself is deprecated ?

What is the alternative way to resolve this error ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate [StatisticsService](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/jmx/StatisticsService.html) is deprecated from 4.0, currently there are no alternative.
But according to the [link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6190), if you use `spring`, you can still use the service.

Comment: No, I am not using Spring so apart from using spring is there any way ?

Comment: did you see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254093/running-hibernate-4-3-with-jmx-without-spring/

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I had a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] to required type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] for property 'sessionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found` after upgrading from hibernate 4.0.1 to 4.3.5. The reason was the usage of the statistics service.