# Hibernate JMX library ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring, hibernate, intellij-idea, jmx

I have `hibernate-jmx-3.5.4-Final.jar` in `target/myapplication/WEB-INF/lib` which suppose to be the place where applications runs but there is error:

```
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service' defined in class path resource [com/sprhib/init/PersistenceContext.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService]: Factory method 'service' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/stat/StatisticsImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1760) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$240(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/818766100.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService]: Factory method 'service' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/stat/StatisticsImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/stat/StatisticsImpl
    at org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService.<init>(StatisticsService.java:59) ~[hibernate-jmx-3.5.4-Final.jar:3.5.4-Final]
    at com.sprhib.init.PersistenceContext.service(PersistenceContext.java:74) ~[PersistenceContext.class:na]
    at com.sprhib.init.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fdb98e8.CGLIB$service$0(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sprhib.init.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fdb98e8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$40bd800.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sprhib.init.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fdb98e8.service(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    ... 73 common frames omitted

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service' defined in class path resource [com/sprhib/init/PersistenceContext.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService]: Factory method 'service' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/stat/StatisticsImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1760)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$240(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/818766100.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService]: Factory method 'service' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/stat/StatisticsImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/stat/StatisticsImpl
    at org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService.<init>(StatisticsService.java:59)
    at com.sprhib.init.PersistenceContext.service(PersistenceContext.java:74)
    at com.sprhib.init.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fdb98e8.CGLIB$service$0(<generated>)
    at com.sprhib.init.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fdb98e8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$40bd800.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.sprhib.init.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fdb98e8.service(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 73 more
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jmx</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I navigate to source code there is error. I think I don't have to modify source code of downloaded library, right?

[image]

Comment: Which hibernate version you are using?

Comment: <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/stat/StatisticsImpl
```

As per this exception StatisticsImpl class not found which is included in hibernate-core.jar library.

Please try following dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hope it may help you.!!

Comment: Is there a way to use latest hibernate version and `hibernate-jmx`?

Comment: check this link you will get better idea.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606092/hibernate-upgrade-statisticsservice