# Replacement or workaround for org.hibernate.jmx.statisticsservice in hibernate 5.2.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have upgraded hibernate 3.x to 5.2.1 in my application. After upgrade, I am getting following error when I run my application,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService] for bean with name 'clientRegHibernateStatistics' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:447)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:220)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1402)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    ... 36 more
```

I have google to find the solution. I came to know as **Hibernate StatisticsService is deprecated from 4.0** and removed in hibernate 5.2.1.

Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606322 and https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/deprecated-list.html

I am using spring 4.3.2 version with hibernate 5.2.1 for my application.

What is the quick workaround or replacement for **org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService** ?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a work around they suggest to use your own spring bean. From [Hibernate JIRA HHH-6190](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6190)

```
public class HibernateStatisticsFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Statistics> {

  @Autowired
  private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  @Override
  public Statistics getObject() throws Exception {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = ((HibernateEntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory).getSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory.getStatistics();
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return Statistics.class;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then you can export this as MBean: [From Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-mbean-server)

Comment: Is this solution verified? I got a runtime exception `Cannot instantiate remote class org.hibernate.stat.internal.StatisticsImpl`.

Comment: @JBT looks like no update on that ticket, maybe newer version of spring/hibernate pair might work?

Comment: I ended up creating a class like this: https://gist.github.com/JianbaoTao/ca9f955eb3b972750ead19d5cb5e88e1

It's dumb, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Hibernate statistics mechanism is not enabled, so you need to activate it using the following configuration property:

`<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>`

To expose the Hibernate metrics via JMX, you also need to set the hibernate.jmx.enabled configuration property:

`<property name="hibernate.jmx.enabled" value="true"/>`

It is recommended to use Hibernate 5.4.2+ this mechanism seem broken in previous version.